# Regex - Coverting URLs to clickable links

Tags: regex, url, hyperlink, clickable

We have some regex code that converts URLs to clickable links, it is working but we are running into issues where if a user submits a entry where they forget to space after a period it thinks it's a link as well.

example: End of a sentence.This is a new sentence

It would create a hyperlink for **sentence.This**

Is there anyway to valid the following code against say a proper domain like .com, .ca ect..?

Here is the code:

`$url = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';`

`$output = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', trim($val[0]));`

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: The `(http)?` is optional, should it be optional? There are also numerous capturing groups, do you need those as well or could you also use a more general pattern?

Comment: Is your question about removing the last `.` or about validating TLDs?

Comment: Basically I want it to ignore a scenario when a user makes a typo and the code converts it to a URL -> sentence.This and only convert say google.com or google.ca ect